# Is there a way to fix my screen grid in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I have been following a book on learning java with relation to android studio and am currently busy with the first project which is a find the submarine type game. For the game we had to draw a grid of squares on the screen. For some reason though, while my horizontal lines are fine, my vertical lines darken and then skip a square.

output: https://ibb.co/RvzjjZ1

Here's the draw method which draws the grid:

```
 void draw(){
    gameView.setImageBitmap(blankBitmap);

    //Wipe the screen with a white colour
    canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255,255,255,255));

    //Change the paint colour to black
    paint.setColor(Color.argb(255,0,0,0));

    //Draw the Vertical Lines of the grid
    for(int i = 0; i < gridWidth; i++){
        canvas.drawLine(blockSize * i, 0,
                blockSize * i, numberVerticalPixels,
                paint);
    }

    //Draw the horizontal lines of the grid
    for(int i = 0; i < gridHeight; i++){
        canvas.drawLine(0,blockSize*i, numberHorizontalPixels,blockSize*i, paint);
    }

    //Re-size the text appropriate for the score and distance
    paint.setTextSize(blockSize*2);
    paint.setColor(Color.argb(255,0,0,255));
    canvas.drawText("Shots Taken: " + shotsTaken +
            "  Distance: " + distanceFromSub,
            blockSize, blockSize*1.75f, paint);


    Log.d("Debugging", "In draw");
    printDebuggingText();`
}
```

Here's the whole code:

```
//These are all the classes need for the sub hunters game

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.view.Display;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.util.Random;

public class SubHunter extends Activity {

    //These variables can be *seen*
    //through out the subhunter class
    int numberHorizontalPixels;
    int numberVerticalPixels;
    int blockSize;
    int gridWidth = 40;
    int gridHeight;
    float horizontalTouched = -100;
    float verticalTouched = -100;
    int subHorizontalPosition;
    int subVerticalPosition;
    boolean hit = false;
    int shotsTaken;
    int distanceFromSub;
    boolean debugging = true;

    //Here are all the objects
    //of classes that we need to do some drawing
    ImageView gameView;
    Bitmap blankBitmap;
    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;

    /*
       Android runs this code just before the player sees the app
       This makes it a good place to add the code for the
       one time setup phase
    */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Get the current device's screen resolution
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        //Initialize our size based variables
        //based on the screen resolution
        numberHorizontalPixels =size.x;
        numberVerticalPixels = size.y;
        blockSize = numberHorizontalPixels/gridWidth;
        gridHeight = numberVerticalPixels/blockSize;

        //Initialize all the objects ready for drawing
        blankBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(numberHorizontalPixels,
                numberVerticalPixels,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        canvas = new Canvas(blankBitmap);
        gameView = new ImageView(this);
        paint = new Paint();

        //Tell android to set our drawing
        //as the view for this app
        setContentView(gameView);

        Log.d("Debugging", "In onCreate");
        newGame();
        draw();
    }

    /*
        This code will execute when a new game needs to be started.
        It will happen when the app is first started and after the
        player wins a game
     */
    public void newGame(){
        Random random = new Random();
        subHorizontalPosition = random.nextInt(gridWidth);
        subVerticalPosition = random.nextInt(gridHeight);
        shotsTaken = 0;

        Log.d("Debugging", "In newGame");

    }

    /*
        Here we will do all the drawing. The grid lines, the HUD
        and the indicator.
     */
    void draw(){
        gameView.setImageBitmap(blankBitmap);

        //Wipe the screen with a white colour
        canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255,255,255,255));

        //Change the paint colour to black
        paint.setColor(Color.argb(255,0,0,0));

        //Draw the Vertical Lines of the grid
        for(int i = 0; i < gridWidth; i++){
            canvas.drawLine(blockSize * i, 0,
                    blockSize * i, numberVerticalPixels,
                    paint);
        }

        //Draw the horizontal lines of the grid
        for(int i = 0; i < gridHeight; i++){
            canvas.drawLine(0,blockSize*i, numberHorizontalPixels,blockSize*i, paint);
        }

        //Re-size the text appropriate for the score and distance
        paint.setTextSize(blockSize*2);
        paint.setColor(Color.argb(255,0,0,255));
        canvas.drawText("Shots Taken: " + shotsTaken +
                "  Distance: " + distanceFromSub,
                blockSize, blockSize*1.75f, paint);


        Log.d("Debugging", "In draw");
        printDebuggingText();
    }

    /*
        This part of the code will handle detecting that the player
        has tapped the screen.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        Log.d("Debugging", "In onTouchEvent");
        takeShot();

        return true;
    }

    /*
        The code here will execute when the player tapes the screen.
        It will calculate the distance from the sub and decide a hit
        or miss.
     */
    void takeShot(){
        Log.d("Debugging", "In takeShot");
        draw();
    }

    //This code says "Boom!"
    void boom(){

    }


    //This code prints the debugging text
    void printDebuggingText(){
        paint.setTextSize(blockSize);
        canvas.drawText("numberHorizontalPixels = " + numberHorizontalPixels,50 ,blockSize*3, paint );
        canvas.drawText("numberVerticalPixels = " + numberVerticalPixels,50 ,blockSize*4, paint );
        canvas.drawText("blockSize = " + blockSize,50 ,blockSize*5, paint );
        canvas.drawText("gridWidth = " + gridWidth,50 ,blockSize*6, paint );
        canvas.drawText("gridHeight = " + gridHeight,50 ,blockSize*7, paint );
        canvas.drawText("horizontalTouched = " + horizontalTouched,50 ,blockSize*8, paint );
        canvas.drawText("verticalTouched = " + verticalTouched,50 ,blockSize*9, paint );
        canvas.drawText("subHorizontalPosition = " + subHorizontalPosition,50 ,blockSize*10, paint );
        canvas.drawText("subVerticalPosition = " + subVerticalPosition,50 ,blockSize*11, paint );
        canvas.drawText("hit = " + hit,50 ,blockSize*12, paint );
        canvas.drawText("shotsTaken = " + shotsTaken,50 ,blockSize*13, paint );
        canvas.drawText("debugging = " + debugging,50 ,blockSize*14, paint );
    }

}
```